# R command for stcox in Stata

Tags: r, survival, stata

What is the equivalent command in R for the `stcox` command in Stata?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In package [survival](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/survival/index.html), it's `coxph`.  John Fox has a nice introduction to using coxph in R:

- [Cox Proportional-Hazards Regression for Survival Data](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/contrib/Fox-Companion/appendix-cox-regression.pdf)

Answer (score 5):

In case you're looking for a quick code translation.

Assuming your Stata and R variables are the same...

```
stset time, failure(fail)
stcox var1 var2
```

in Stata translates to

```
library(survival)
coxph(Surv(time, fail) ~ var1 + var2)
```

in R assuming your dataframe is attached.

Note: if you're comparing results in R and Stata, R uses the Efron method to handle ties by default while Stata uses the Breslow method, which is less accurate but slightly quicker to compute.